# JButton polygons producing strange translations

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, polygon

Trying to make a triangular JButton, however unexpected shapes appear in the background, as shown in the picture.

[image: Strange shapes?]

When used in my GUI, the background of the button contains seemingly random parts of other element (instead of just a transformation of the triangle). Resizing the window sometimes changes the shape of the background also. So far I have only tried this on Windows, so I don't know if this is platform specific.

I also don't understand why the triangle is point down, as the second y coordinate is positive.

```
public class TriangleButton extends JButton {

    private Polygon shape;

    public TriangleButton() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        int[] xpoints = {0, 50, 100};
        int[] ypoints = {0, 50, 0};

        this.shape = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize());
        this.setMaximumSize(this.getSize());
        this.setPreferredSize(this.getSize());

        this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gCopy = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        gCopy.fillPolygon(this.shape);

    }
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return this.shape.contains(x, y);
    }
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TriangleButton button = new TriangleButton();

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You've failed to honour the paint chain by not calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any additional painting.  Also, as a general rule, if you `create` it, you should `dispose` of it

Comment: Remember, when overriding methods, you either need to be willing to take over ALL their responsibility or call the `super` method